# Relationship between database tables

Tags: sql-server

I have an existing DB schema like this.Is there a way to create any kind of referential integrity between these two tables. What exactly is the kind of relationship ? Is it many to many with just two classes

`Student` table:

```
ID    Name     CourseID
------------------------
 1    Student1     100023
 2    Student2     100023
 3    Student3     100024  
 4    Student4     NULL
```

`Course` table:

```
ID   CourseID   CourseName
--------------------------
 1   100023      Course1  
 2   100022      Course2  
 3   100024      Course3  
 4   100023      Course6
```

`ID` is the primary key in both the tables. `CourseID` is the column for the relationships.

Comment: Shouldn't CourseID be unique in Course table?

Comment: You seem to have some architectural challenges here. You should not have the CourseID in the student table. You should have 3 tables here.

Comment: it's an existing schema. i was thinking the same like you said  having 3 tables

Comment: The existing schema is bad design. Can you redo it and do it right?

Comment: @Zohar .Student can have multiple courses and multiple students can take same course. But its been done differently in the schema rather than the normal approach of using 3 tables.

Comment: Unless a student always takes exactly *one* course, your schema is probably "deficient." However, given that it is an *existing* schema, you might be "stuck with it." In any case, as Kalmino just described below, you can create "foreign key" constraints quite easily, no matter what the schema looks like. *Be aware(!),* however, that the existing data in "this real-world existing database" might not actually conform to it! **:-/**

Comment: If it's being done "differently," e.g. through repeating-groups, then these constraints *may or may  not(!)* work! You might be about to embark into a **very** messy "journey into `TRIGGER`-land ..." (And, if so, you won't be the first ...)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely.  You can create a Foreign Key constraint between Student.CourseID and Course.CourseID.  You can either do it through SQL Server Management studio directly or by using an ALTER TABLE/ADD CONSTRAINT statement.  Personally, I find the Management Studio easiest to use.

Do a search on "SQL Foreign Key Constraints" and you should find a W3Schools (or something similar) explaining everything you need to know to get started with them.

Comment: Oh snap.  I didn't even notice the schema issue that Sean Lange/Zohar Peled brought up.  Handle that first, before trying any kind of Foreign Key linking.

Comment: i know how to create a foreign key . I am looking answer to this particular problem.

Comment: You asked if there was any way to create a referential link...Regardless, it's appears to be many-to-many because the Course.CourseID is not unique (going to cause all kinds of problems) and Student.CourseID is not unique as you've said that a Student can have multiple courses.  The only thing that would change this is if there's a typo in your demo table and 10023 isn't supposed to show up twice in Course.CourseID.

Answer (score 0):

Looking the table you have described and assuming CourseID would be unique in Course table  it is many to one/zero relation between Student  and Course

or can be said zero/one to many relation between Course and Student table.

but I feel this is not a good design it should have three tbales

Course table

Student table

Bridge table for Course and  Student